# Google Map android lock on specific Country or State

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin

is there anyway to lock the google maps to a specific country/state, lets say I want only to view Arizona on the google maps and when I get off the specific state it will go back to the state or much better will lock and will disable to scroll whenever they get off the state.  Can someone help me with this?  Thanks.

Comment: Given: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/controls#scroll_pan_gestures what have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Morrison Chang, No I haven't yet, but is there anyway to set the `google maps` to view only the state or country? let say if state is selected the rest of the state will disable or disappear?. But yeah your suggestions above is a great suggestion, that is very useful though.

Comment: I doubt it, Google would have to do it for every country, state, region, province, county, town, city, politically defined and contested area. Not impossible for them, but not sure of the benefit to them either. If you are providing features to every app developer you want to make is as minimal as possible. Another thing to look at for highlighting areas is [Ground Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/groundoverlay) or use [Tile Overlays/Providers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay).